# Prisma: How can we order by the numbers of Childs? (GraphQL)

Tags: graphql, prisma

With Prisma,

How can we order by the numbers of childs (nested)?

Examples: 
Let's assume we have 2 objects: Post and Comment. 1 Post has many comments.

What is the query to get All posts order by the number of comments?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that at the moment.

There is an opened issue for that: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/95